# If $G$ is a simple, no loops graph, with n vertices and e edges, whose vertices have degree k or k+1 then G has $n_k$ vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

**Question:**

> Decide if the following expression is true or false. Prove or give a counterexample.
>
> If $G$ is a simple, no loops graph, with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges, whose vertices have degree $k$ or $k+1$ then G has $n_k=(k+1)n-2e+1$ vertices of degree $k$.

**Attempt:**

I think this is false, I tried to construct a counterexample but I think I haven't gotten it right.

Consider the graph $G$ of $1$ vertex and no edges. Then the $deg(v)=0$ and $n_k=k+2$.

I then separated in two cases, $deg(v)=k$ and $deg(v)=k+1$.

If $k=0$ then $n_0=2$ which is false, as there's only one vertex of degree $0$.

If $k+1=0$ then $n_{-1}=1$ which doesn't make much sense as the degree must be nonnegative, so where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your graph $G = (V, E)$ is undirected and we denote the degree of a vertex $v$ as $deg(v)$. In graph theory, we have the following identity:
$$
\sum_{v \in V} deg(v) = 2e
$$

So now suppose the # of vertices with degree $k$ is $x$ (so those with degree $k+1$ is $n - x$), we have
$$
\sum_{v \in V} deg(v) = k\cdot x + (k+1)\cdot(n-x) = 2e
$$
Solving this equation, we have
$$
x = (k+1)n - 2e
$$

Comment: @bof The "+1" in $n_k$ is a typo, I think. If not, every simple finite graph whose vertices are of degree either $k$ or $k+1$ serves as a counterexample. So personally, I prefer the first possibility, otherwise the question is too trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Number of vertices with degree k =$n_k$
Number of vertices with degree k+1 =$n_k$ 
Number of edges    = e 
Number of vertices = n 
n=$n_k +n_{k+1}$

> $k*n_k+(k+1)*n_{k+1} = 2e$ [sum of degrees of a graph= 2e] 
>   $k*n_k+k*n_{k+1}+n_{k+1} = 2e$ 
>   $k*(n_k+n_{k+1})+n_{k+1} = 2e$ 
>   $k*n +n_{k+1} =2e$

$n_{k+1} =2e-kn$

> $n_k =n-n_{k+1}$ 
>   $n_k =n-(2e-kn)$ 
>   $n_k =n-2e+kn$

- $n_k = (k+1)n-2e$

If degrees are k and k+2 then

$n_k = \frac{(k+2)n-2e}{2}$

General form for vertices with degree k and k+r

- $n_k = \frac{(k+r)n-2e}{r}$

Therefore the given expression $n_k = (k+1)n-2e+1$ is wrong.

Comment: Could you show me a graph that's a counterexample?

Comment: [link] http://i.stack.imgur.com/IEkAD.png
In this graph, vertices with degree 3 is 4. But the given expression gives n3= 4*6-(2*10)+1 = 24-20+1 =5